# twitter-bootstrap-rails maximum column width

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails-3, column-width, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I am working on a really simple app that is styled using twitter-bootstrap-rails.  One my model index page there is a table that displays the data and it looks really great.  The problem is that if someone enters a really long string of unbroken text (like a URL for example) into one of the fields, the width of that column with stretch and squish all the other columns.  I would like some way to enforce the width of the column and tell the browser to break up really long words.

What I have tried to do so far was for each `<th>` I have added a class and tried to use CSS to control the width.  Here is an example

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="column1"> etc
      <th class="column2"> etc
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="column1"> etc
      <td class="column2" etc
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And then I was using this in my stylesheet

```
th.column1 { width: 300px;
  word-wrap:break-word;}
td.column1 { width: 300px;
  word-wrap:break-word;}
```

So far that isn't working for me, and I wonder if I need to be duplicating my code so much.

Comment: ,Does Twitter-bootstrap-rails have something different then bootstrap itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up fixing it on my own.  What I did was use max-width instead of width

```
th.column1 td.column1 { max-width:300px; word-wrap:break-word; }
```